# How to Scale a Graph Using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(data=response, aes(x=beak_size, fill=generation))
```

This is my code so far, I keep getting a barely readable graph, and when I've tried to make my histogram using basic R I keep getting this error for the following code:

```
hist(response$beak_size, col="lightblue",
     main="Graph",
     xlab="Beak Size", ylab="Count")

Error in hist.default(response$beak_size, col = "lightblue", main = "Graph",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Please check the `str(response)`. May be the `beak_size` is not numeric

Comment: might be good to add an image of your barely readable graph, to help us understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hist()`:

```
hist(as.numeric(response$beak_size), col="lightblue",
     main="Graph",
     xlab="Beak Size", ylab="Count")
```

If your variable measurement scale is not quantitative, you should use a `barplot()`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the column is not numeric.  We can convert to `numeric` and it should work

```
response$beak_size <- as.numeric(as.character(response$beak_size))
```